# How can I explain a unicorn that shoots spinning horns?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

I am designing a horse with a drill bit shank on top of its head that act as a projectile, my question is what mechanism(s) would be possible for a horse to evolve so it can snipe anything without relying on magic? How does it handle the recoil and can it be on semi or fully automatic if so how does it stores it magazine of horns? No cyborg no magic and yes to genetically augmented mutant.

Comment: Is it microscopic in size?

Comment: @Samuel Not necessarily as long as it takes on the shape of a horse with a pointy little thing on its head and it is not a toy.

Comment: @sumelic it simply means you can't simply strap a dwarf holding a live AK47 on the head of a horse.

Comment: First I lol'ed at the question. Then my jaw dropped when the question turned out to be a ***duplicate***. Crazy world.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like the cone snail, but that was also [my answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/21075/6751) for the Natural Projectile Weapons question. The unicorn could have something like the radula sac in it's neck where horns are grown and stored, then pushed up through it's head. Using compressed air or mussels like a frog tongue the horn is thrown toward the target, then a new horn is pushed up. The horn could be hollow and full of poison too if you want, since piercing power might be a factor. If the question gets reopened, this is my answer :)

Comment: @AndreiROM That's Worldbuilding.SE :D

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stretch, but what about using the same mechanism the [Bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Bombardier_beetle) uses to shoot hot liquid?  It mixes  hydroquinone and hydrogen peroxide to make a very hot liquid that it sprays at its enemies.  You could add some hardened compartment in the unicorns head that protects the rest of it from the heat.  The chamber would be sealed by the horn and the valves to the organs holding the Bombardier beetle chemicals.  The pressure buildup would propel the horn.

As far as multiple horns, I'm not really sure how that could work..  Maybe the horn (if it were small) would be regrown after a day or two.  Or maybe there could be multiple horns and the "unicorn" (now something else) could pick which one it shot from?